# l2tp сервер отвечает не с того ip

Tags: linux, iptables, l2tp, ppp

Есть сервер с 2мя ip. Нужно подключиться вторым линком l2tp. Первый по дефолту ходит нормально, а вот второй не слушается.

Настроил маркировку конектов и ip rule.

Анализ пакетов показывает следующее:
L2TP управляющие пакеты ходят как положено. `PPP LCP` **идут в дефолт** и маркировке не подчиняются.

```
ip route add default via x.x.x.1 table 100 
ip rule add from x.x.x.134 lookup 100
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp0s10 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.134 
ip rule add fwmark 100 lookup 100 
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i enp0s10 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 100
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

В логах - попытки conf-request с обоих сторон и падает.

Вот тут видно проблему:

```
16:04:36.124214 IP x.x.x.134.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[TLS](56620/0)Ns=1,Nr=2 ZLB
16:04:36.124357 IP x.x.x.134.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[TLS](56620/49902)Ns=1,Nr=3 *MSGTYPE(ICRP) *ASSND_SESS_ID(11516)
16:04:36.124440 IP x.x.x.134.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[TLS](56620/0)Ns=2,Nr=3 ZLB
16:04:36.124536 IP x.x.x.134.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[TLS](56620/0)Ns=2,Nr=3 ZLB
16:04:36.124597 IP x.x.x.134.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[TLS](56620/0)Ns=2,Nr=3 ZLB
16:04:36.126682 IP z.z.z.z.9809 > x.x.x.134.1701:  l2tp:[TLS](3768/0)Ns=3,Nr=1 ZLB
16:04:36.185226 IP z.z.z.z.9809 > x.x.x.134.1701:  l2tp:[TLS](3768/11516)Ns=3,Nr=2 *MSGTYPE(ICCN) *TX_CONN_SPEED(100000000) *FRAMING_TYPE(S) RX_CONN_SPEED(100000000)
16:04:36.187111 IP x.x.x.134.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[TLS](56620/49902)Ns=2,Nr=4 ZLB
16:04:36.196933 IP z.z.z.z.9809 > x.x.x.134.1701:  l2tp:[](3768/11516) {LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22}
16:04:36.215326 IP y.y.y.231.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[](56620/49902) {LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 27}
16:04:39.215438 IP z.z.z.z.9809 > x.x.x.134.1701:  l2tp:[](3768/11516) {LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22}
16:04:39.216674 IP y.y.y.231.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[](56620/49902) {LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 27}
16:04:42.215606 IP z.z.z.z.9809 > x.x.x.134.1701:  l2tp:[](3768/11516) {LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22}
16:04:42.220181 IP y.y.y.231.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[](56620/49902) {LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 27}
16:04:45.223446 IP y.y.y.231.1701 > z.z.z.z.9809:  l2tp:[](56620/49902) {LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 27}
```

z.z.z.z - клиент

попробую тут
https://github.com/xelerance/xl2tpd/issues/137

Comment: А маркировка тут не причем, она же заворачивает в другую таблице как раз по src ip, а он другой. копайте в сторону конфигов ppp демона, может там что нибудь есть

Comment: если внимательно посмотрите, то я ещё заворачиваю по метке на пакете.

Comment: А кто бы эту марку на пакет поставил ... там проблема то в том, что для ядра это два совершенно разных коннекта. вы марку поставили на коннект когда пришел управляющий запрос. А ppp для своего протокола создала с точки зрения контрака совершенно другой коннект и марка на него разумеется не перешла

Comment: iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
разве не ставит марку на пакет?

Comment: а по поводу разных конектов - конекты мапятся по паре `ип:порт-ип-порт` - какой процесс сидит на этом конекте ядру всеравно пока оно не попало в input

Comment: причем тут процесс. вы же видите, пакет как выглядит y.y.y.231.1701 таким его собрал ppp и как ядру после этого догадаться, что это тот же коннект что бы поставить на него марку ?

Comment: Вот с этого и надо было начинать...но pppd не собирает l2tp пакет.)

Comment: А кто, я думал l2tp так же через pppd идет. ну в общем надо как то воздействовать на тот процесс который этот пакет создает.

Comment: l2tp_ppp в ядре может занимается этими пакостями..

Comment: я надеялся что ответы шлются как в обычных приложениях socket.send_to(z.z.z.z), а срц адрес назначается при отправке.

У вас нет ссылки на то где посмотреть каким образом идет отправка в l2tp?

Comment: еще заметил одно отличие. ppptp похоже тоже собирается целиком в гре, но потом срц адрес меняется и в итоде `bad checksum`

Comment: кстати, даже если пакет шлется send_to(z.z.z.z) он шлется с другого сокета и по стандартному дефолту системы выбирается интерфейс и на него ставится src этого интерфейса. вот если бы можно было в обычной таблице маршрутизации прописать маршрут на z.z.z.z через enp0s10 проблем бы не было. но я так подозреваю, что z.z.z.z заранее не известен и прибить его гвоздями нельзя

Comment: когда известен, когда нет. по разному. но хочется держать 2 конекта одновременно. чтоб при падении первого не было разрыва на л7